# Jstree rename issue. inline editor opens above root node

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jstree

Folks I am having an issue with rename and JsTree. I have created a JS Fiddle to highlight the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/KJYrs/. My scenario is that I'd like to validate that the entered name is not a default name or contains special characters. When I try to fire the rename event after the initial failed attempt the inline editor appears above the root node.

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="source">
$(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"]
    }).bind("rename.jstree", function (event, data) {
        //let's assume I do some vaidation here and it fails
        //so I want to rename until valid
        if (event.type === 'rename') {
            $("#demo1").jstree("deselect_all");
            $("#demo1").jstree("select_node", "#" + data.rslt.obj[0].id);
            $("#demo1").jstree("rename");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="demo1" class="demo">
    <ul>
        <li id="phtml_1">   <a href="#">Root node 1</a>

            <ul>
                <li id="phtml_2">   <a href="#">Child node 1</a>

                </li>
                <li id="phtml_3">   <a href="#">Child node 2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="phtml_4">   <a href="#">Root node 2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions would be  greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears because you call the rename, inside the rename - is not crash, but creates other problems. A simple solution is to call after the rename ends, using the `setTimeout` as:

```
$(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"]
    }).bind("rename.jstree", function (event, data) {
        //let's assume I do some vaidation here and it fails
        //so I want to rename until valid
        if (event.type === 'rename') 
        {
            setTimeout(function(){
               $("#demo1").jstree("deselect_all");
               $("#demo1").jstree("select_node", "#" + data.rslt.obj[0].id);
               $("#demo1").jstree("rename");
            },100);
        }
    });
});
```

And the results:
http://jsfiddle.net/KJYrs/1/

Now you have other problems that you need to solve, a cancel of the rename, and to disable the menu until this ends.

Comment: Aristos Thank you so much! This has been driving me nuts!